# jquery create new divs with sql script

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax, tooltip

Well, I was making a tooltip script, it was working but I realized as soon as I had many tooltips my webpage would get slower, so I tried to change the script to only create what was needed.

This JS finds a 'itemtooltip' class (wich is a img) and then calls the script to create the tooltip.

```
jQuery('.itemtooltip').hover(function(){
    var datas = jQuery(this).data('tip');
    var dataString = "value="+datas;
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.dawnsource.com/work/scripts/createitemtooltip.php",
    data: dataString ,
    success: function(msg) {
      jQuery('#bg-overlay').html(msg);
    }
    });
    var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
    console.log(offset)
    var width = jQuery(this).outerWidth();
    jQuery('#tooltip-container' + jQuery(this).data('tip')).css({top:offset.top, left:offset.left + width + 10}).show();
}, function(){
    jQuery('#tooltip-container' + jQuery(this).data('tip')).hide();
});
```

Script:

```
<?
$aux = $_POST['value'];
$query2 = "SELECT u.Id_item, u.name, u.effect, u.passive, u.image, u.cost FROM items AS u WHERE u.name = $aux";
$resultado2= mysqli_query($con,$query2);

$l = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado2);
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $l['name']);
$string2 = $l['passive'];
if ($string2 == 'null') $string2 = ' ';

$name = $l['name'];
$cost = $l['cost'];
$effect = $l['effect'];

echo '<div class="tooltip-container" id="tooltip-container$string">
    <div style="width:300px; margin:3px;">
        <div class="title" style="width:200px; float:left;">$name</div>
        <div class="text" style="float:left;">Cost:</div><div style="color:#FC0; float:left; font-size:12px;"> $cost<img src="http://www.dawnsource.com/work/images/random/vim2.png" width="15" height="15"></div>
        <div class="effects" style="width:250px; float:left;">$effect</div>
        <? if ($string2 != " " ){ ?>
        <div style="width:280px; font-weight:bold; float:left; font-size:12px;">
        Passive:<div class="text" style="float:left;">$string2</div>
        </div>
        <? } ?>
    </div>
</div>';

?>
```

The problem is that the echo isnt outputing the variables, its creating something like this:

```
<div class="tooltip-container" id="tooltip-container$string">
```

etc...

I've tried with echo 'text'+variable+'text'; but doesnt output anything in that way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but something which you could take into consideration: Instead of requesting a HTML string to your PHP-part, it's maybe a nicer approach to just load JSON data and use that in JS. What's also nice: write the DOM you need for the tooltip once in your HTML and modify the content with JS, set the absolute position for it and ... no more DOM injection necessary. A lot quicker I think. Just my penny of thoughts.

Comment: The second approach sounds nice, how could I do that? make the ajax query the information then how would I change the content of the tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<div class="tooltip-container" id="tooltip-container'.$string.'">
```

'text'+variable+'text' is the JS way to connect your variable to string out put. Generally speaking in PHP you'd want to break your encapsulation by using, in your case '..' with the variable in between.